# next.js wrong img on route change

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have this page [trainers].tsx and I load data and everything works fine except my img. It loads but before it is loaded I can see the previous img on page ../2

For example, If I go to ../1 page the image loads etc. If I go to ../2 I can the image from ../1 page and after a second or so, I can see the image for ../2 page. What is wrong?

```
...

export async function getServerSideProps({ params }: { params: any }) {
  const program = await API.getProgram(Number(params.trainers));
  return { props: { program } };
}

function Trainers(props: any): JSX.Element {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { trainers } = router.query;

  const { data } = useQuery(
    `program-${trainers}`,
    API.getProgram.bind(null, trainers),
    {
      initialData: props.program,
    }
  );

  return (
    <Layout>
      {JSON.stringify(data.preview)}
      <div className={"min-h-screen relative"}>
        <div className={"h-screen relative"}>
          <div className={"w-full h-screen bg-black"}>
            <Image
              src={data.preview}
              layout={"fill"}
              objectFit={"cover"}
              alt={"preview"}
            />
          </div>

         ...
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default Trainers;
```

Comment: put that query call in a use effect with trainer as the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Can try something like this to make sure the data is cleared when you change the page. Can add a loader for the image when the data is empty.

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ params }: { params: any }) {
  const program = await API.getProgram(Number(params.trainers));
  return { props: { program } };
}

function Trainers(props: any): JSX.Element {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [queryData, setQueryData] = useState(null)
  const { trainers } = router.query;

   const _useQuery = () ={
    let _data = null
    const { data } = useQuery(
      `program-${trainers}`,
      API.getProgram.bind(null, trainers),
      {
        initialData: props.program,
      }
    );
    if(data){
      _data = data
    }
    setQueryData(_data)
   }

  useEffect(() => {
    _useQuery()
    return () => {
      setQueryData(null)
    };
  }, [trainers]);

  return (
    <Layout>
      {queryData && JSON.stringify(queryData.preview)}
      <div className={"min-h-screen relative"}>
        <div className={"h-screen relative"}>
          <div className={"w-full h-screen bg-black"}>
            {queryData ? <Image
              src={queryData.preview}
              layout={"fill"}
              objectFit={"cover"}
              alt={"preview"}
            /> : <Loader/>}
          </div>

         ...
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default Trainers;
```

Comment: you can't use useQuery in useEffect, it is a hook from react-query

Comment: I updated it, I can't test it, though. That useQuery that you are using, does it return a status?  {status:success,data:[],error:null}.  Something like this? If it returns a status, this would be easier.

Comment: You still use useQuery inside of useEffect. You just move it to the function. Thanks for the help, I understood what you wanted to achieve